# What differences exist between relates and relationship class in a geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, relationship-class, relates

I am doing a project for my class and I was just wondering what differences exist between relates and relationship class in a geodatabase? And why and when would you use a relationship class over a relate or join?

Comment: I think this question is too broad because it seeks to assemble a list of differences.

Answer (score 1):

A quote from [ArcGIS documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/relationships/deciding-between-relationship-classes-joins-and-re.htm) summarizes it:

> Relationship classes help ensure referential integrity. For example,
>   the deletion or modification of one feature could delete or alter a
>   related feature. Furthermore, a relationship class is stored in the
>   geodatabase, which makes it accessible to anyone who uses the
>   geodatabase.
>
> On-the-fly relationships, also called relates, are defined as a
>   property of an ArcMap layer. Use them for improved editing
>   performance.
>
> Joins are best suited for labeling and symbology. You define joins
>   through the relational database to make standard SQL queries cross the
>   database as well as a variety of data sources.

Some examples are presented at the [Esri GeoNet Community](https://community.esri.com/groups/esri-training/blog/2018/09/25/relates-and-relationship-classes-explained).